# Using Large Lookup Table in Single MultiCore Machine with PySpark

Tags: python, dictionary, mapreduce, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large lookup table which holds integers as keys and lists of strings as values. I need this lookup table to do some filtering and transformation on data which I load through spark.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local[20]")
conf.setAppName("analysis")
conf.set("spark.local.dir", "./tmp")
#conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "20g")
#conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "20g")
conf.set("spark.python.worker.reuse", "yes")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)
```

While starting pyspark I am even using the `--driver-memory 20g` option.

My machine has 500 GB memory and 27 cores. I first load a dictionary in the memory called `lookup_tbl` which has 17457954 rows.

When I try to run the following code, I don't get any output for more than 10 minutes. After waiting for this long, I shut down the process. I need the lookup table feature. I have even tried using the `broadcast` feature.

```
sc.broadcast(lookup_tbl)
def clean_data(x, transform=lambda k: (int(k[0]), "\t".join(k[1:]))):
  x = x.split('\t')
  return transform(x)


def check_self(x):
  from_id = x[0]
  to_id = x[1]
  self_ = 1
  try:
    common_items = set(lookup_tbl[from_id]).intersection(set(lookup_tbl[to_id]))
  except KeyError:
    common_items = set()
  if len(common_items ) < 1:
    common_items = set("-")
    self_ = 0
  return (((from_id, to_id, k, self_) for k in common_items ))

pair = sc.textFile("data/pair.tsv").map(lambda x: clean_data(x, transform=lambda k: (int(k[0]), int(k[1])))).flatMap(check_self)
csv_data = pair.map(lambda x: "\t".join("%s" for k in xrange(len(x))) % x)
csv_data.saveAsTextFile("out/pair_transformed")
```

Is this an issue with spark or am I not running this correctly? Also, I have tried setting various values for executor and driver memory (`~20g`), but got no improvements.

From what I understand, spark is first trying to serialize this dictionary before sending it to all the local processes. Is there a way it can use this dictionary from the common location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all to access broadcast variable you have to use its `value` property:

```
# You can use get instead of catching KeyError
s1 = set(lookup_tbl.value.get(from_id, set()))
s2 = set(lookup_tbl.value.get(to_id, set()))
common_items = s1.intersection(s2)
```

To avoid broadcasting you can load `lookup_tbl` locally inside `mapPartitions`:

```
def check_partition(iter):
   lookup_tbl = ...
   for x in iter:
       yield check_self

identity = lambda x: x
pair = (sc.textFile(...)
    .map(lambda x: clean_data(...)
    .mapPartitions(check_partition)
    .flatMap(identity))
```

If `lookup_tbl` is relatively large it can be still quite expensive.There a quite a few ways you can handle this:

1. Use SQLite connection instead of local variable.

   ```
   import sqlite3
   conn = sqlite3.connect('path/to/lookup.db')

   c.execute("SELECT key FROM lookup WHERE id = '%s'" % from_id)
   s1 = {x[0] for x in c.fetchall()}
   c.execute("SELECT key FROM lookup WHERE id = '%s'" % to_id)
   s2 = {x[0] for x in c.fetchall()}
   common_items = s1.intersection(s2)
   ```

   It is easy to setup and should be fast enough if data is properly indexed
2. Use a single database server for lookups. MongoDB should work just fine and with proper memory mapping you significantly reduce overall memory footprint
3. Use `join` instead of broadcast

   ```
   swap = lambda x: (x[1], x[0])

   def reshape1(record):
      (k1, (items, k2)) = record
      return (k2, (k1, items))

   def reshape2(record):
      (k1, (items1, (k2, items2))) = record
      return (k1, k2, set(items1) & set(items2))

   pairs = sc.textFile(...).map(lambda x: clean_data(...))

   n = ... # Number of partitions
   lookup_rdd = sc.parallelize(lookup_tbl.items()).partitionBy(n)

   lookup_rdd.join(lookup_rdd.join(pairs).map(reshape1)).map(reshape2)
   ```

Comment: Thanks using `value` fixed my issue.